# How to add nofollow on all external links without plugin?

Tags: plugins, permalinks, links, seo, nofollow

I have tried many plugins, which are doing the thing I want, but they are blocking my other plugins (1 in particular, which is indispensable for my site). Anyhow; how can I add a nofollow on all my outgoing anchors? Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it :

1/ create a filter to access the post content before it's displayed on page.
See http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

2/ Inside your fonction called (ie : my_the_content_filter in the example from the Codex)
adapt this code :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037592/how-to-add-rel-nofollow-to-links-with-preg-replace

Cheers !

Comment: In case anyone else comes across this post, there is a solution that perfectly fitted my needs here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/a-plugin-for-having-rel-nofollow-in-posts