# Security concerns with external links

Tags: security, links

In [this article](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/) I read, that using `<a href="" target="blank">` is related to some security issues. They recommend `rel=noopener`.

How do I implement this in my WP-Installation? Which file is the relevant one? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Since WordPress 5.1 (see [#43187](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43187)) it ships with the [`wp_targeted_link_rel()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_targeted_link_rel/) function, that adds `noreferrer` and `noopener` relation values to all *anchor* elements that have a `target`.

This function is used to filter through the various input data just before saving it, e.g.

- post title,
- post content,
- post excerpt,
- comment content,
- term description,
- link description,
- link notes,
- user description.

Since 5.2 the following improvements are made:

- [#46421](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/46421) handles the Text and HTML widgets.
- [#43280](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43280) handles the Image Media widget.
- [#43290](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43290) handles the Menus.

There are open tickets to further refine it, e.g.

- [#46886](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/46886) to avoid false positive from the `data-target` attribute.
- [#46580](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/46580) asks if there's any reason to add the relations for any values of `target`.
- [46316](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/46316) to not let it corrupt JSON content.
- [#46479](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/46479) to handle the comment fields.

If you have some custom user input that allows external links, then you could use:

```
$text = wp_targeted_link_rel( $text );
```

to handle it.

The default relation values `'noopener noreferrer'` are also filterable through the [`wp_targeted_link_rel`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L3060) filter.

Answer (score 0):

"Wich file is the relevant one" = All files that allow user generated content to be viewed.

You have to change hook into the_content to change the URLs and add noopener

There is a great answer here: [How to add nofollow on all external links without plugin?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104450/how-to-add-nofollow-on-all-external-links-without-plugin) (and here: [A plugin for having rel="nofollow" in posts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/a-plugin-for-having-rel-nofollow-in-posts) ) you should look into.