# Why does modifying the "read more" link remove the link class?

Tags: functions, read-more

I'm using the following code ([found on the WordPress.org site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Modify_The_Read_More_Link_Text)) to modify my `(more…)` text:

```
//Modify "read more" text
function modify_read_more_link() {
    return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">(Continue…)</a>';
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
```

The code works as expected, in the sense that `(more…)` is properly replaced by `(Continue…)`, and the link works as intended. However, there is a peculiar issue: The class `more-link` has disappeared, which means styling doesn't work. I attempted to circumnavigate the issue by adding styling inline (`return '<a  style="font-size:0.8em;" href="' . get_permalink() . '">(Continue…)</a>';`) but that hasn't worked either.

**My Question**:
Why has the class `more-link` disappeared, and how can I restore it?

*Note:* I add the code above to `functions.php`; I'm not using a child theme.

Comment: Above code is working as expected. May be some plugin is affecting the hook. Try disabling all plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps there is an issue with the "Ellipsis" HTML character you are using?

```
function modify_read_more_link() {
    return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">( Continue &hellip; )</a>';
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
```

Comment: Good idea, though it sadly didn't work :(

Comment: Did you try without the round brackets around the text - just using the word "Continue" - for example - no technical reason it should fail, but just wondering..?

Comment: That didn't work either. Do you happen to know where the whole more-link behavior is stored (i.e. which php file)? I feel as if I'm trying to reinvent the wheel, when I could just go to the original place and alter 6 characters (if I only knew where it was stored)

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.5.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L369

Comment: But, no-one will agree that it's a good idea to alter core, so just write your own query to get the post content and alter how you present it in your templates.

Comment: Notice the use of the force_balance_tags() function on the output - might be having an effect..

Comment: I found the culprit! I've been using the code found [on this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/a-plugin-for-having-rel-nofollow-in-posts/159570#159570) and as a result, the class="more-link" was stripped because of this. I'll mark your reply as an answer, and award you the bounty once the interface allows.

Comment: Ahh! Good news :)